# SQLite3 Regular Expressions and Schema Constraints

Tags: regex, database, sqlite

In a SQLite3 CREATE TABLE statement, can I use a regular expression to enforce a particular constraint? Specifically, I am trying to require that an inputted URL is valid. I know there are other ways of doing this besides using regular expressions, but because of the structure of my project, this is the method I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expressions only after you've installed a user-defined `REGEXP` function; SQLite doesn't have one by default.

But if you have it, you can use `REGEXP` also in a `CHECK` constraint.